# tox uses wrong version of pip when multiple versions of python are installed

Tags: python, version, pip, setup.py, tox

I have a build box which supports python 2.4, 2.6 and 2.7. This leads to installing various versions of pips as required in their own python installations. I'm using `tox` to run tests through `setup.py`.

Whenever I run a `{python2.7_installation_dir}/bin/python setup.py test`, this results in a `.tox` directory. Inside `.tox` directory I run

```
py27/bin/pip --version 
pip 1.4.1 from {my_package}/.tox/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)


[buildbot@BUILD-SERV-01 .tox]# python2.7 
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 20 2013, 15:33:09) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pip
>>> pip.__version__
'1.5.2'
```

So the version of pip inside .tox directory is 1.4.1 where as pip installed for python interpreter that I'm using to execute the `setup.py test` is 1.5.2. This leads to errors when running tests as it uses pip to install the directories and some of them come from external sources and in 1.5.2 we need to set explicitly --allow-external --allow-unverified flag for one of the module which doesn't exist in 1.4.1, which results in an error each time i invoke tests through tox.

There is only one python2.7 installation and it is installed from source. But I think it was running pip 1.4.1, but now been upgraded to use 1.5.2. How tox can use the old version? Is there any `.pth` file or something that could have been left behind which needs clearing up?

I could drop `tox` and run pytests directly but I'd prefer to run them via `tox`.
Please let me know if you want to see the logs, I can update the question with the log.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: No I gave up on tox cowardly due to lack of time to look into it!

Answer (score 1):

`tox` creates a virtualenv in `.tox/py27`, `.tox/py35` etc depending on the python versions you test with (i.e. based on you  `envlist` in `tox.ini` or the argument to the `-e` option).
`tox` then installs `pip` into this virtualenv, and your packages, and all packages your package is dependent upon.

On further runs, to save time, the virtualenv is reused and only your package is reinstalled (and possible dependencies updated). Your `pip` will stay at the original version unless you do:

```
./tox/py27/bin/pip install -U pip
```

or reinitialises the complete virtualenv with:

```
tox -r -e py27
```

(or `tox -r` for all `.tox` virtualenvs for all python versions in your `envlist`).

If you further want to analyse how `tox` does the setup, first call:

```
tox -r -e py27 -vv
```

from the output you can see the **recreate** step:

```
py27 recreate: /src/site-packages/your/package/.tox/py27
  removing /src/site-packages/your/package/.tox/py27
setting PATH=/src/site-packages/your/package/.tox/py27/bin:/opt/python/2.7/bin:........
  /src/site-packages/your/package/.tox$ python -m virtualenv --python /opt/python/2.7.13rc1/bin/python py27 >/src/site-packages/your/package/.tox/py27/log/py27-0.log
```

Now you go to the .tox directory and redo the virtualenv creation verbose:

```
cd .tox; rm -rf py27
python -m virtualenv --python /opt/python/2.7/13rc1/bin/python py27
```

From that log you'll see that it uses the latest (cached) version of `pip`. As your normal install gets you the latest `pip` version, there should be no need to clean/update `pip`'s cache.

Answer (score -2):

Use this approach: create a tox.ini file at the same level as your setup.py and use it to tell tox which versions to run, like [here](https://github.com/pycontribs/tendo/blob/master/tox.ini)

Comment: This does not answer the question. It is not the Python version which is sought but the pip one.